# sharing code behind between pages

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have 3 wpf pages which have exact same code-behind but xaml (design) are different.
Is there any way to share those code behinds for all files?

[image: wpf structure]

Comment: Best way I can think of is to use the MVVM pattern. Then all three views can share the same ViewModel.

Comment: This would be a perfect scenario for using MVVM indeed